# Underscore, how to sort when keys are nested

Tags: json, sorting, nested, underscore.js

I have a complex JSON array: a typical array element is the following:

```
{
    "runner": {
        "_id": "5625ebf3d0ca02d7092d46e3",
        "title": "pid",
        "url": "runner",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5w24e437wb35c31w4fc47wf2",
            "avatar": {
                "src": "cew52ee16r037fc89625946621226597c7922ac.jpg"
            }
        },
        "start_date": "2015-11-11T19:30:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2015-11-11T21:30:00.000Z",
        "privacy": {
            "scope": "public"
        },
        "tqx_payment": {
            "invoice_data": {
                "tax_name": "",
                "tax_rate": 0,
                "vat_number": "",
                "address": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "country": "",
                "company": ""
            },
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "published": true,
        "deleted": false,
        "timezone": "Europe/Rome"
    },
    "_id": "56264096a1ae9d316635b9b5",
    "type": "default"
}
```

I want to sort all the elements in the array by *runner.start_date*. Is this possible? How?

Comment: Please add an answer with your solution and accept it, instead of adding a "solved" addendum to the question.

Comment: @Konamiman I did it, but I can accept my answer tomorrow

Comment: @3000 Great, thanks. That's the standard behavior in StackOverlow when someone solves his problem by himself. By the way, I have edited the question to remove the solution text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED] by trial and error this way:

```
_.sortBy(JSONArray, function(itm) {
   return [itm.runner.start_date];
});
```